# Is there a way to verify user permissions with python's win32security

Tags: python, windows, security, ssh, pywin32

I know about win32security.LogonUser. What I want to do is check credentials that were entered to know whether or not they match a user on the local windows machine, and password, so that I can grant them access to the windows machine via the network. The idea is to have a pythonic ssh server made with paramiko that has default windows authentication. What I don't want to have to do is log the user out each time a new connection is established or have the authentication process fail because the user is already logged in. Is there a way to verify a user on windows without creating a login session?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I was just using the `LogonUser` function erroneously. There does exist a enumerated value to hand the function to tell it that you would like a security context back for executing a process with that user's credentials and will throw an exception if a bad username or password is ever passed in.

In other words, this is the acceptable way of calling the method so that it doesn't throw an exception if the user is already logged in or has more than one session running.  This is also a good method to be able to verify user credentials on the fly for any application's needs:

```
try:
    hUser = win32security.LogonUser(username,
                                    domain,
                                    password,
                                    win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                                    win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT) 
except win32security.error:
    print "Failed"
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: I tested this on a machine that was connected to a domain and it seemed to work alright.  However, when I attempt to use this on a machine that only has local users, it is still throwing exceptions for users that are logged in.  More investigation is needed.